# Removing parentheses and comma

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm importing Data from a database into python data frame. Now, I wish to use the data for further analysis, however, I need to do a little cleaning of the data before using. Currently, the required column is formatted like 
`('2275.1', '1950.4')`. The output that I require should look like:`2275.1` and `1950.4` exclusively. 
can someone please help

Comment: Did you try `str.replace()`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code writing service, please show your efforts

Comment: Hi EdChum, I did try a few approaches, however I wasn't able to solve. I tried finding solutions to my approach, but since I didn't find anything. Hence, I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

```
import re
x = "'('2275.1', '1950.4')'"
y = re.findall(r'\d+\.\d', x)
for i in y:
  print i
```

Output:

```
2275.1
1950.4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
print re.findall(r"\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?\b",test_str)
```

You can simply do this.

or

```
print map(float,re.findall(r"\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?\b",x))
```

If you want `float` values.

Answer (score 0):

Try `ast.literal_eval`, which evaluates its argument as a constant Python expression:

```
import ast

data = ast.literal_eval("('2275.1', '1950.4')")
# data is now the Python tuple ('2275.1', '1950.4')

x, y = data
# x is '2275.1' and y is '1950.4'
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume, that the string you provided is actually the output of python. It is hence a tuple, containing two strings, which are numbers. If so and you would like to replace the `'`, you have to convert them to a number format, such as `float`:

```
a = ('2275.1', '1950.4')
a = [float (aI) for aI in a] 
print a
[2275.1, 1950.4]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The original output is <pyodbc.row>

Answer (score 0):

Here a non-regex approach:

```
data = (('2275.1', '1950.4'))


result = data[0]# 0 means the value in the first row
result2 = data[1]# 1 means the next row after 0


print result
print result2
```

Output:

```
>>> 
2275.1
1950.4
>>>
```